# Can jellyfish sting outside of water?

Tags: marine-biology

According to my understanding of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnidocyte) on the stinging cells of the jellyfish, the mechanism of delivering the toxic missile is largely due to water pressure. Does that mean that a jellyfish on land (or brought out water) is unable to, or perhaps less efficient at, delivering its stings?

Comment: The _wiki_ article did state the cnidoblasts **uses** the chemical gradient and osmosis to sting. So i guess it needs those two factors to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**
Jelly fish can sting out of the water and even when they are considered to be dead.

**Background**
I do not have detailed scientific literature available. However, popular sources generally and equivocally warn against touching jelly fish, even on land and even when they appear to be dead. In fact, dead box jelly fish can be as dangerous as live ones ([ABC News](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-02-09/beachgoers-warned-not-to-touch-box-jellyfish/6079146)).

<sub>**Credible sources**

 - [National Poison Control Center](http://www.poison.org/articles/2009-jun/jellyfish-a-pain-at-the-beach)

 - [UK Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/destinations/europe/united-kingdom/articles/What-to-do-if-you-are-stung-by-a-jellyfish/)

 - [ABC News](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-02-09/beachgoers-warned-not-to-touch-box-jellyfish/6079146)</sub>